# Vertical hr size and, more space between tables and align o text

Tags: html

I am trying to achieve similar look to this one below. I cannot use external css file but it has to be embdeed into html tags.

[image]

So far i got such html:

```
<table style="margin:0px 35px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 5px;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 1:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 2:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 3:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attributedwdwdwdwdgffewfwefwedewdwedwedwedabc 4:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 15:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin:0px 0px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 5px;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><hr width="1" size="200" background-color="cornflowerBlue"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin:0px 0px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 5px;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Höhe:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Breite:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">55 cm, 99 cm, 20 cm, 60 cm, 100 cm, 1000 cm, 9000 cm, 77777 cm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Länge:</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff">Value 9</td>
    </tr>
</table><div style="clear:both !important;">
</div>
<br>
</br>
```

It gives such result:

[image]

Do not look please at gray background for some rectangles because it just for some test.

I have following problems marked on above picture:

1. I would like this hr vertical size to be similar to the target on table height and space between left table and right table more close. Right now i put fixed size.
2. I would like in such case when left text is wrap then for instance Value 4 to be at the position a bit up to be inline with first line.
3. I would like to have more spce between what i marked.

Hope you get my points. Thank you for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

To try address your questions:

1. Didn't fully understand this point, there's no `hr` in your code. However, if you want that vertical line to match the height of the table, draw it using a border on the table.
2. If you want text to be vertically aligned regardless of wrapping, then use css property `vertical-align: top;` for all your `td`s ... because `vertical-align: middle;` causes Value 4 to be aligned at the middle of your long wrapped text.
3. Add padding-left (and reduce min-width and width accordingly)

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT** Added code

```
<h1 style="max-width: 740px; text-align: center;">Information details</h1>
<table style="margin:0px 35px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 0;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h2>General</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 1:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid grey;padding-left:30px;">Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 2:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid grey;padding-left:30px;">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 3:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid grey;padding-left:30px;">Value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:black;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attributedwdwdwdwdgffewfwefwedewdwedwedwedabc 4:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid grey;padding-left:30px;">Value 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: white">Attribute 15:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid grey;padding-left:30px;">Value 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show line with border-right, this table with the <hr> is useless
<table style="margin:0px 0px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 5px;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><hr width="1" size="200" background-color="cornflowerBlue"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff"></td>
    </tr>
</table> -->
<table style="margin:0px 0px 0px -10px;font-size:15px;border-spacing:5px 0;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:separate;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h2>Others</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Höhe:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;padding-left:30px;">Value 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Breite:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;padding-left:30px;">55 cm, 99 cm, 20 cm, 60 cm, 100 cm, 1000 cm, 9000 cm, 77777 cm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:120px;min-width:120px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;color:white;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #b4b4b4">Länge:</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:175px;min-width:175px;height:30px;margin:5px;padding:5px;font-family:Raleway,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background-color: #fff;padding-left:30px;">Value 9</td>
    </tr>
</table><div style="clear:both !important;">
</div>
<br>
</br>
```

Comment: 1. There is: <td rowspan="4"><hr width="1" size="200" background-color="cornflowerBlue"></td>
2 & 3 could you show my html updated of this?

Comment: Updated HTML, tell me if thats what you want

Comment: What if i would like to add 3 text as in target picture : Information Details, general, Others - can you update to that so i mark as an answer fully

Comment: @Arie edited code to include Information details, general and others.